# Scrapy yield only last data and merge scrapy data into one

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping some news website with scrapy framework, it seems only store the last item scraped and repeated in loop

I want to store the Title,Date,and Link, which i scrape from the first page
and also store the whole news article. So i want to merge the article which stored in a list into a single string.

Item code

```
import scrapy
class ScrapedItem(scrapy.Item):
# define the fields for your item here like:
title = scrapy.Field()
source = scrapy.Field()
date = scrapy.Field()
paragraph = scrapy.Field()
```

Spider code

```
import scrapy
from ..items import ScrapedItem


class CBNCSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'kontan'
start_urls = [
    'https://investasi.kontan.co.id/rubrik/28/Emiten'
]

def parse(self, response):
    box_text = response.xpath("//ul/li/div[@class='ket']")
    items = ScrapedItem()

    for crawl in box_text:

        title = crawl.css("h1 a::text").extract()
        source ="https://investasi.kontan.co.id"+(crawl.css("h1 a::attr(href)").extract()[0]) 
        date = crawl.css("span.font-gray::text").extract()[0].replace("|","")


        items['title'] = title
        items['source'] =source
        items['date'] = date

        yield scrapy.Request(url = source,
                             callback=self.parseparagraph,
                             meta={'item':items})

def parseparagraph(self, response):
    items_old = response.meta['item']  #only last item stored
    paragraph = response.xpath("//p/text()").extract() 
    items_old['paragraph'] = paragraph #merge into single string
    yield items_old
```

I expect the output that the Date,Title,and Source can be updated through the loop.
And the article can be merged into single string to be stored in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined an empty dictionary and put those variables within it. Moreover, I've brought about some minor changes in your xpaths and css selectors to make them less error prone. The script is working as desired now:

```
import scrapy

class CBNCSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'kontan'
    start_urls = [
        'https://investasi.kontan.co.id/rubrik/28/Emiten'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for crawl in response.xpath("//*[@id='list-news']//*[@class='ket']"):
            d = {}
            d['title'] = crawl.css("h1 > a::text").get()
            d['source'] = response.urljoin(crawl.css("h1 > a::attr(href)").get())
            d['date'] = crawl.css("span.font-gray::text").get().strip("|")
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=d['source'],
                callback=self.parseparagraph,
                meta={'item':d}
             )

    def parseparagraph(self, response):
        items_old = response.meta['item']
        items_old['paragraph'] = response.xpath("//p/text()").getall()
        yield items_old
```

Comment: I already tried the chaining request, and it was a success. However merging all paragraph in article into one still a problem, since MYSQL can't accept list. I already tried using string join, with a whitespace separator seem gives no luck.

Comment: Nevermind i forgot to remove [0] in store_db function. So it only store the first character.

Comment: There should not be any issue in your output if you try this `items_old['paragraph'] = ' '.join([' '.join(elem.split()) for elem in response.xpath("//p/text()").getall()])` but this is highly discouraged as it is not user friendly.